# Парсинг большого XML на PHP

Tags: php, xml

Написал парсер, который парсит yandex YML с товарами, а так же копирует все картинки товаров и заносит всё в базу, картинки в папки разлаживает.
Файл в котором 400 товаров парсит нормально, а вот файл с 27411 товаров очень долго проходит.
В настройках выставляется какое количество товаров парсить за один раз, выставлял разное количество, толку нет. За каждый проход парсер загружается заново.

```
$yml = simplexml_load_file($shop_info["yml_location"]);
```

Можно ли как-то получать товары по 10 или 20 штук из файла? Что бы не грузить постоянно весь файл. Хостинг не выдерживает.
Зато на денвере грузит всё чётко быстро.

Comment: У гдето вас опечатка. В теме написно что парсится xml в вопросе - yml. Непонятно с чем именно вы работаете.

Comment: Ваш парсер - это dom парсер. Он в любом случае загружает все в память и потом строит дерево. А это требует обычно двух-трехкратного объема памяти (по сравнению с исходным файлом). Вам нужно взять sax парсер  - он грузит по немного и проходит файл в один проход. Да, его использование немного сложнее, но результат может порадовать.

Comment: Вопрос к гуглю https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3+SimpleXML+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B+%D1%81+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8 Первый ответ для примера http://dpyatkov.ru/2012/01/12/simplexmlreader/

Comment: @Arnial xml = yml = одно и тоже.
KoVadim про sax тоже читал, но может есть вариант всё же мой доделать, всё таки в нём много кода уже, не охота заново тратить день.

Comment: Для начала надо изложить проблему не в терминологии домохозяйки, а приведя конкретные цифры и сообщения об ошибках. Что такое "очень медленно"? В чем конкретно выражается " Хостинг не выдерживает"? Какие ошибки скрипт выдает?

Comment: замерьте время выполнения на критичных участках сценария и предоставьте проблемный участок кода, который работает слишком долго.

Answer (score 1):

Для парсинга больших XML файлов средствами PHP лучше всего подходит библиотека [XMLReader](http://php.net/XMLReader).

Библиотека поддерживает обработку сжатых XML файлов.

```
$xmlfile = 'compress.zlib://dir/largefile.xml.gz';
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xmlfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант оптимизации процесса импорта. Можно написать XSLT преобразователь XML в CSV, использовать для преобразования http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html в режиме командной строки, а потом уже работать с чистыми данными, без смысловой разметки, средствами PHP. Разборка и обработка XML контента средствами PHP более ресурсоемкая операция.